# Rearrange seaborn countplot x-axis

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I am using seaborn countplot on a pandas data series. The series looks like this:

```
df['col'] = 

['Week 4',
 'Week 4',
 'Week 3',
 'Week 1',
 'Week 5',
 'Week 3',
 'Week 3',
 'Week 2',
 'Week 4',
 'Week 5',
 'Week 5',
 'Week 4',
 'Week 5',
 'Week 2',
 'Week 5',
 'Week 1',
 ..
 ..
 ..
 ..
]
```

I'd like rearrange the x-axis to start with Week 1, Week 2, Week 3.... and so on.

```
sns.countplot(LeaseComp['Weeks on market'])
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sorted values like:

```
L = ['Week 4',
 'Week 4',
 'Week 3',
 'Week 1',
 'Week 5',
 'Week 3',
 'Week 3',
 'Week 2',
 'Week 4',
 'Week 5',
 'Week 5',
 'Week 4',
 'Week 5',
 'Week 2',
 'Week 5',
 'Week 1',

]
LeaseComp = pd.DataFrame(L, columns=['Weeks on market'])

sns.countplot(LeaseComp['Weeks on market'].sort_values())
```

[image: g]

Answer (score 1):

For seaborn:

```
sns.countplot( x = 'Weeks on market', data = LeaseComp, 
              order = sorted(LeaseComp['Weeks on market'].unique()))
```

Same plot can be achieved by what BEATHUB has posted, but it may produce some warnings.

Answer (score 0):

You may try,

```
sns.countplot(x= LeaseComp['Weeks on market'].sort_values())
```